# how to disable or hide the right and left arrow from keyboard with ViewPager android

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I am trying to disable left and right on the `keyboard` with this code but `viewPager` on the press of left and right `button` change the state of the pager.

```
edComment.setOnEditorActionListener(
    new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NAVIGATE_PREVIOUS
                || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NAVIGATE_NEXT
                || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_PREVIOUS
                || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT
                ) {


            return false;


        }
        // Return true if you have consumed the action, else false.
        return false;
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried to change the inputType in editText field ?

Comment: yes, I change with .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyboard app can show whatever keys it wants.  There is no way to force it not to show certain buttons, and even if there was another keyboard wouldn't follow the same rules.

Comment: Thanks, Sir but How I disable the moving of viewPager state on these button click

Answer (score 7):

You can extend the ViewPager and override the `arrowScroll` method like this:

```java
public class Wizard extends ViewPager {
    @Override
    public boolean arrowScroll(int direction) {
        // Never allow pressing keyboard arrows to switch between pages
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to @Gabe Sechan button are not hide or disable so I am doing like that

```
  @Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.i("your tag", "Keycode: " + keyCode);
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
           Log.e("Click","left");

           /* for (int n = 0; n < count; n++) {

                setCurrentPage(arrayListView.get(n + 1));
            }*/


            pager.setCurrentItem(getItem(+1), true);
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
            Log.e("Click","right");


            pager.setCurrentItem(getItem(-1), true);



            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
            Log.e("Click","up");
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
            Log.e("Click","Down");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```